# Who first conceptualized the space rendezvous?

Tags: history, rendezvous

For the Apollo mission, there was a debate on which mode is better - the Earth orbit rendezvous (EOR) or the lunar orbit rendezvous (LOR). Who was the first person to introduce the concept of space rendezvous?

Comment: Probably some sci-fi author from the late 1800s.

Comment: I don't know about space rendezvous in general, but Yuri Kondratyuk pioneered the concept of Lunar Orbit Rendezvous in 1919.

Comment: @GdD: Thanks. I read about it. That was about travelling to Moon. I think it would have originated from our using different modes of transport to reach our destination while on earth (Take a taxi, go to airport, take the flight, catch a railway from the new airport, get down at a railway station and then get a bus to reach the destination. Or trans shipment of goods while in transport.. etc.) BUT WHO would have thought of it first ? That too in space!!!

Comment: It's an interesting historical question, do you want to know who first imagined the concept or who did the first serious calculations?

Comment: @GdD: Honestly both. But more importantly, who "FIRST" thought of (imagined the concept) the rendezvous in space.. It is possible that the person who thought of space rendezvous also did some more theoretical research, and did the required calculations (wonder what sort of calculations would be required to verify if this is possible). Only physical trials would have highlighted the problems and the technique to overcome the same.

Comment: Honestly, the concept probably predates humans.  The moon is big, and obviously far away, going there and meeting someone on the way or on the way back is almost unavoidable.  And then turning an accidental meeting into a purposeful meeting is just a small step. Some of our predecessors were smart enough to have had the idea.

Comment: @jmoreno: On a lighter note, If the idea "predates humans", it must be the aliens who would have thought of it, &  obviously knowing about interplanetary travel... But seriously speaking, people at large do not seem to have recorded "WHO" thought of SPACE RENDEZVOUS in general (& not EOR or LOR etc). Or perhaps it was deemed to be too naive to make a note of it.

Comment: Or it was too obvious to note. Seriously, pre-human hominids on planet earth.  They didn’t have all the details, but going to the moon and meeting someone on the way back was probably first thought up by them.  By the time anyone (aka humans in the relatively recent past) knew more (aka bring your own oxygen) we had a rough idea of how to do so. The basic idea has almost certainly been around forever.  All that has changed is the details on mechanics.

Comment: @jmoreno: You seem to be a believer in ET life.. That's another big subject. We can surely discuss it on a related Stack site (if any). Let me know if there is any such site. Just a passing remark - Things which were in-explicable; have been, in the past, attributed to "GOD" or "FATE", now they are (also) being attributed to "Aliens"....

Comment: @Niranjan: no idea what you are talking about.  Don’t have an opinion on ET life.  Much more certain that Ardipithecus kadabba existed.  Not evidence, but wouldn’t surprise me if they were the first to have the idea.

Comment: @jmoreno: Your ref. of "pre-human hominids" made me think you are talking about "Extra-Terrestrials - ET" AKA - Aliens. (Instead of Apes, as per the theory of evolution). Please excuse me for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Glad we’re past that then, perhaps a more colloquial way of saying that would have avoided the misunderstanding: the basic idea is older than dirt. The only important change in the last little bit of forever is we can now apply practical engineering to the idea. Asking about when the idea first occurred is like asking about when the idea of living longer due to medicine first occurred.

Comment: @Jmoreno: Your analogy of :asking about the idea of rendezvous first occurred, is like asking about when the idea of living longer due to medicine first occurred" seems logical but I think is far too stretched. One overcomes the diseases by taking medicine is everyone's experience, & thus leading to the conclusion that we will stay longer with medicines. However, at least for me, it is difficult to believe that the idea of "Space Rendezvous" would have been generated out of similar experience. Anyway, had there been any record of it, I think Google would have known it. Thanks for your posts.

Comment: That’s because you are projecting modern understanding of the difficulty onto past dreams. For starters, they wouldn’t have thought of it as **space** rendezvous because they had no concept of space, no idea what the atmosphere is, let alone the idea that it doesn’t extend out past the moon. But the idea of going there doesn’t rely upon that, just seeing it is enough.  https://astronomy.com/news/2019/06/the-first-imaginative-moon-landing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of the question mentions the Apollo missions, but the title of the question and later comments indicate that the expected answer is something like: **'these' people came up with the concept of orbital rendezvous and suggested how it could be done**.

It is obviously impossible to completely prove or verify which human did this first, but the simplified equations that are used for relative motion in orbit are called **Euler-Hill equations** or **Hill-Clohessy–Wiltshire equations**. [source](http://www.ingaero.uniroma1.it/attachments/1978_LectureNoteEulerHillEqs.pdf)

Digging a bit further into these names, this is what I found-

**1590s**

Tycho Brahe discovers the inequality with

> the mean motion counted from New Moon or Full Moon, he found  the
> Moon about 2/3 of a degree behind its mean position a week before New
> Moon and  before Full Moon, and about 2/3 of a degree ahead of its
> mean position a week after  New Moon and after Full Moon.
> [source](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/002182860803900402?journalCode=jhaa)

**1776**

Johann Albrecht **Euler**(son of Leonhard Euler) formulates this problem in a way different than his predecessors who pondered the 3 body problem. [source](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/002182860803900402?journalCode=jhaa)

**1878**

George William **Hill**

> provided the first complete mathematical solution to the problem of
> the apsidal precession of the Moon's orbit around the Earth, a
> difficult problem in lunar theory first raised in Isaac Newton's
> Principia Mathematica of 1687.[3] This same work also introduced what
> is now known in physics and mathematics as the "Hill differential
> equation", which describes the behavior of a parametric oscillator and
> which made an important contribution to the mathematical Floquet
> theory.
> [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_William_Hill)

This formulation helps see how 2 bodies orbiting 1 central body behave. And [this](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eekolemen/publications/AAS_04_294_Maui_Conference.doc.pdf) paper says that the Clohessy-Wiltshire equations were the first to use them as relative motion for spacecraft rendezvous.

**1960**

**W.H.Clohessy** and **R.S.Wiltshire** of *The Martin Company* published [a paper](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/8.8704) in 1960, titled '*Terminal Guidance System for Satellite **Rendezvous**.*' The paper explains the term *Rendezvous*, derives equations, describes requirements and so on. This was the earliest one that I could find.

To summarize from above points:

The genesis of the requirement of deliberate *Rendezvous* was sometime before 1959.
W.H.Clohessy and R.S.Wiltshire where probably the first people to show how it could be done. The tools they used however, came from a problem that was discovered in 1590s, formulated in 1776 and well worked on from 1878.

Comment: 1- Yes. I expect the answer to be like: 'these' people came up with the concept & how it could be done. The reason I used the term Apollo while asking the question is I came across the word (in space context) while reading about our journey to the moon. I then read that first "orbital rendezvous" was tried out earlier in 1965, by Gemini 6&7, (though they did not dock with each other), and hence was curious to know who first thought of the concept. 2- I accept your conclusion that Clohessy & Wiltshire, were the ones, because no one else has even this info. Thanks.

Comment: A Gemini vehicle docked with an unmanned target vehicle.

Answer (score 5):

> Lunar orbit rendezvous was first proposed in 1919 by Ukrainian
> engineer Yuri Kondratyuk, as the most economical way of sending a
> human on a round-trip journey to the Moon.
>
> Dr. John Houbolt would not let the advantages of LOR be ignored. As a
> member of Lunar Mission Steering Group, Houbolt had been studying
> various technical aspects of space rendezvous since 1959 and was
> convinced, like several others at Langley Research Center, that LOR
> was not only the most feasible way to make it to the Moon before the
> decade was out, it was the only way. He had reported his findings to
> NASA on various occasions but felt strongly that the internal task
> forces (to which he made presentations) were following arbitrarily
> established "ground rules." According to Houbolt, these ground rules
> were constraining NASA's thinking about the lunar mission—and causing
> LOR to be ruled out before it was fairly considered.[9]
>
> In November 1961, Houbolt took the bold step of skipping proper
> channels and writing a nine-page private letter directly to associate
> administrator Robert C. Seamans. "Somewhat as a voice in the
> wilderness," Houbolt protested LOR's exclusion. "Do we want to go to
> the Moon or not?" the Langley engineer asked. "Why is Nova, with its
> ponderous size simply just accepted, and why is a much less grandiose
> scheme involving rendezvous ostracized or put on the defensive? I
> fully realize that contacting you in this manner is somewhat
> unorthodox," Houbolt admitted, "but the issues at stake are crucial
> enough to us all that an unusual course is warranted."[10][11]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit_rendezvous#Advocacy)

> When the Apollo Moon landing program was started in 1961, it was
> assumed that the three-man command and service module combination
> (CSM) would be used for takeoff from the lunar surface, and return to
> Earth. It would therefore have to be landed on the Moon by a larger
> rocket stage with landing gear legs, resulting in a very large
> spacecraft (in excess of 100,000 pounds (45,000 kg)) to be sent to the
> Moon.
>
> If this were done by direct ascent (on a single launch vehicle), the
> rocket required would have to be extremely large, in the Nova class.
> The alternative to this would have been Earth orbit rendezvous, in
> which two or more rockets in the Saturn class would launch parts of
> the complete spacecraft, which would rendezvous in Earth orbit before
> departing for the Moon. This would possibly include a separately
> launched Earth departure stage, or require on-orbit refueling of the
> empty departure stage.
>
> Wernher von Braun and Heinz-Hermann Koelle of the Army Ballistic
> Missile Agency presented lunar orbit rendezvous, as an option for
> reaching the moon efficiently, to the heads of NASA, including Abe
> Silverstein, in December 1958.[5] During 1959 Conrad Lau of the
> Chance-Vought Astronautics Division supervised a complete mission plan
> using lunar orbit rendezvous which was then sent to Silverstein at
> NASA in January 1960. Tom Dolan, who worked for Lau, was sent to
> explain the company's proposal to NASA engineers and management in
> February 1960.[6] [5] This alternative was then studied and promoted
> by Jim Chamberlin and Owen Maynard at the Space Task Group in the 1960
> early Apollo feasibility studies.[7] This mode allowed a single Saturn
> V to launch the CSM to the Moon with a smaller LEM.[Note 3] When the
> combined spacecraft reaches lunar orbit, one of the three astronauts
> remains with the CSM, while the other two enter the LEM, undock and
> descend to the surface of the Moon. They then use the ascent stage of
> the LEM to rejoin the CSM in lunar orbit, then discard the LEM and use
> the CSM for the return to Earth. This method was brought to the
> attention of NASA Associate Administrator Robert Seamans by Langley
> Research Center engineer John C. Houbolt, who led a team to develop
> it.
>
> Besides requiring less payload, the ability to use a lunar lander
> designed just for that purpose was another advantage of the LOR
> approach. The LEM's design gave the astronauts a clear view of their
> landing site through observation windows approximately 4.6 metres (15
> ft) above the surface, as opposed to being on their backs in a Command
> Module lander, at least 40 or 50 feet (12 or 15 m) above the surface,
> able to see it only through a television screen.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_orbit_rendezvous#Advocacy)

So the concept of a rendezvous in space was proposed by Yuri Kondratyuk in 1919 and by Hermann Oberth in 1929 and by the member of the British Interplanetary Society Harry E. Ross in 1948.

Wernher von Braun preferred the Earth Orbit Rendezvous at first but was convinced by John Houbolt of the advantages of the Lunar Orbit Rendezvous in a campaign that lasted from 1960 to 1962.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems Houbolt already knew the concept. He advocated this for Lunar orbit, while Braun did the same for Earth Orbit. I was curious to know who first thought of it (& made it known to the world).

Comment: Can you please take the time to provide some analysis in your own words? See the [Help Center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for more info.

Comment: @called2voyage: I did visit the "Help Center". Wonder what part of my question did you find contains "plagiarism"... Anyway, I have no intention of indulging in those sort of things. I am reading, understanding and writing down what I have understood about "OUR (human's) JOURNEY TO THE MOON". In the process, I keep coming across many doubts, which I ask on this forum. Many times I get satisfactory answers with some additional interesting information. Sometimes my questions get rejected as either a duplicate or irrelevant etc.  Thats Ok. I am curious to know "WHO" invented space rendezvous.

Comment: @Niranjan This isn't a comment on your question. This is a comment on Uwe's answer.